# Durante la deserializacion de un xml en un objeto pierdo los minutos y segundos de una fecha

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

Durante la deserializacion de un xml en un objeto pierdo los minutos y segundos de una fecha. La fecha que recibo es:   2020-11-05:21:38+21:38

El código de la deserialización es:

```
        var text = File.ReadAllText("./order.xml");
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

        Order Output;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (var xmlReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer= new XmlSerializer(typeof(Order));
                Output = (Order)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader); 
            }
        }
```

Tras hacer una investigación, el problema esta en el formato de la fecha:

2020-11-05:21:38+21:38

Si pongo una fecha con otro formato (ejemplo 2020-11-05:21:38), ya me funciona, pero esta fecha me viene de otro sistema y no puedo cambiar su formato.

¿Alguien sabe como hacer para que la deserialización funcione con este formato de fecha?

Comment: Intenta añadir el atributo `[XmlElement(DataType = "date")]` en la clase `Order` a la propiedad donde viene la fecha a ver si asi te lo hace correctamente.

Comment: Si lo anterior no te funciona, tal vez tengas que hacer lo que se explica [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118855/579895) para hacer la conversion de `DateTime` por tu cuenta